# Swift - unable to access typealias properties once set

Tags: swift, xcode, for-loop, swift5, type-alias

I have a load of UIView objects created using a class called 'SheetField'.

The objects are usually initialised throughout the app as follows:

```
objectx = SheetField(title: "example", value: "example")
```

I need to add an additional property 'letter' to these objects to access in one part of the app and so I have created a typealias as follows:

```
typealias NewSheetField = (field: SheetField, letter: String?)
```

I am therefore declaring these field objects as follows:

```
private var fieldX: NewSheetField
private var fieldY: NewSheetField   
private var fieldZ: NewSheetField
```

And I initialise them like this:

```
fieldX = NewSheetField(field: SheetField(title: "example", value: "example"), letter: nil)
fieldY = NewSheetField(field: SheetField(title: "example", value: "example"), letter: nil)
fieldZ = NewSheetField(field: SheetField(title: "example", value: "example"), letter: nil)
```

Then I want to assign specific letters to these fields. So, I have a letter dictionary:

```
private let letters = [0: "A", 1: "B", 2: "C", 3: "D", 4: "E", 5: "F", 6: "G", 7: "H"]
```

And a loop to apply the letter values:

```
func createLettersForFields(fields: [NewSheetField]) {
    for (index, var f) in fields.enumerated() {
        if let letterToAdd = letters[index] {
            f.letter = letterToAdd
        }
    }
}
```

So I call the function like this:

```
createLettersForFields(fields: [fieldX, fieldY, fieldZ]
```

However, I can't seem to assign the letters correctly. I added a couple of print statements into the loop:

```
func createLettersForFields(fields: [NewSheetField]) {
    for (index, var f) in fields.enumerated() {
        if let letterToAdd = letters[index] {
            f.letter = letterToAdd
            print("\(f.letter)")
            print("\(fieldX.letter)") 
        }
    }
}
```

The loop obviously prints out f.letter fine each time (f being the field we are passing in) but it won't print out a specific field letter at all - the value is always nil. What I expected was that print("(fieldX.letter)") would print nil until the loop hit the fieldX field and then would print the assigned value. Obviously the print statement is unimportant, but it explains why I am unable to access fieldX.letter in other functions where I need it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated on this one.

UPDATE:

I added a conditional statement into the loop as follows:

```
if f == fieldX {
print("TEST")
}
```

And added a breakpoint into this condition. I'm never hitting this part so clearly the 'f' that I am using here is not equal to the field I am initialising... And yet when I print 'f' from the function and print 'fieldX' from the init, they seem to be the same object:

```
PRINTED FROM METHOD: (field: <SheetField: 0x125e56240; frame = (0 0; 0 0); layer = <CALayer: 0x2824c70a0>>, letter: Optional("A"))

PRINTED FROM INIT : (field: <SheetField: 0x125e56240; frame = (0 0; 0 0); layer = <CALayer: 0x2824c70a0>>, letter: nil)
```

UPDATE 2:

Strange goings on! I simplified the for loop and took out the enumerated part:

```
func createLettersForFields(fields: [NewSheetField]) {
    for var field in fields {
        if field == fieldX {
            fieldX.letter = "A"
        }
    }
}
```

This works and assigns 'A' to fieldX. When I log fieldX.letter I get "A". However, when I then swap 'fieldX' for 'field' it still won't assign:

```
func createLettersForFields(fields: [NewSheetField]) {
    for var field in fields {
        if field == fieldX {
            field.letter = "A"
        }
    }
}
```

Here, the print log returns nil.
Surely by the time it hits field.letter = "A", field is fieldX !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got caught in the ***value type trap***.

In this line

```
for (index, var f) in fields.enumerated() {
```

`f` is a copy of `fields`, the parameter array and the objects `fieldX`, `fieldY` and `fieldZ` remain unmodified. Don't you wonder that you don't get an error about *`fields` cannot be modified because it's a constant*?

Even the fields in the array `[fieldX, fieldY, fieldZ]` are copies of the three fields.

If keeping the references to the original objects is crucial use classes which are reference types.

Otherwise you have to create the array as variable, pass it as `inout` and modify the items directly in the array. Note that the `element` in the enumeration is unused because you have to assign `letterToAdd` directly to the item in the array

As `letter` is optional the optional binding is redundant

```
private var fieldX = NewSheetField(field: SheetField(title: "example", value: "example"), letter: nil)
private var fieldY = NewSheetField(field: SheetField(title: "example", value: "example"), letter: nil)
private var fieldZ = NewSheetField(field: SheetField(title: "example", value: "example"), letter: nil)

private let letters = [0: "A", 1: "B", 2: "C", 3: "D", 4: "E", 5: "F", 6: "G", 7: "H"]

func createLettersForFields(fields: inout [NewSheetField]) {
    for (index, _) in fields.enumerated() {
        fields[index].letter = letters[index]
    }
}

var theFields = [fieldX, fieldY, fieldZ]
createLettersForFields(fields: &theFields)
print(theFields)
```

Be aware that even with this way the contents of `private var fieldX/Y/Z` won't be changed.

Comment: Excellent thank you! I had a feeling it was something to do with value vs reference types but just couldn't quite figure it out. Appreciate your help !